# Is there an article that follows In terms of?

Tags: articles

1. In terms of scale and productivity, Taldinskaya Zapadnaya-2 is considered an ideal coal mine.
2. In terms of **a** scale and productivity, Taldinskaya Zapadnaya-2 is considered an ideal coal mine.
3. In terms of **the** scale and productivity, Taldinskaya Zapadnaya-2 is considered an ideal coal mine.

Which one is most suitable?

Comment: 1 and 3 are equally valid.

Comment: 1. is fine. Why do you want to add an article? Basically, it is a good idea not to add extra words without reason, unless you are trying to be creative.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example sentence

> In terms of scale and productivity, Taldinskaya Zapadnaya-2 is considered an ideal coal mine.

is fine when referencing a *general case*.  However, if you wanted to bring particular attention to the scale and productivity of this mine, for example, this mine is productive as a small mine but not as productive when compared to larger mines which may have better *scale*, you might say

> In terms of **its** scale and productivity, Taldinskaya Zapadnaya-2 is considered an ideal coal mine.

or

> In terms of **the** scale and productivity **of** Taldinskaya Zapadnaya-2, **it** is considered an ideal coal mine.